# NullPointerException when set value

Tags: java, database, jsp, nullpointerexception

I have a problem jsp in action class. When I write this code:

```
listRehber.add(new Rehber(
    rs.getString("KISI_ID").toString(),
    rs.getString("AD").toString(),
    rs.getString("SOYAD").toString(),
    rs.getString("UNVANI").toString(),
    rs.getString("GOREVI").toString(),
    rs.getString("FIRMA").toString(),
    rs.getString("ADRES").toString(),
    rs.getString("TEL").toString(),
    rs.getString("FAX").toString(),
    rs.getString("GSM").toString(),
    rs.getString("MAIL").toString(),
    rs.getString("WEB").toString()));
}
```

because maybe db will be empty value. For example DB will have "name" value but it will not have "fax". How can ı pass this nullpointer exceptions
thank you so much

My `Rehber.class`

```
public class Rehber {
    private String adi = "";
    private String soyadi = "";
    private String unvani = "";
    private String gorevi = "";
    private String firma = "";
    private String adres = "";
    private String tel = "";
    private String fax = "";
    private String gsm = "";
    private String mail = "";
    private String web = "";
    private String id = "";

    public Rehber(String id, String adi, String soyadi, String unvani,
            String gorevi, String firma, String adres, String tel, String fax,
            String gsm, String mail, String web) {

        this.adi = adi; 
        this.soyadi = soyadi;
        this.unvani = unvani;   
        this.gorevi = gorevi;       
        this.firma = firma;     
        this.adres = adres;     
        this.tel = tel;     
        this.fax = fax; 
        this.gsm = gsm;     
        this.mail = mail;   
        this.web = web;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and get/set method

Comment: as has been stated, the npe comes from your toString() calls on the resultset getString() methods. when these return null, you get trapped by the npe. If you want to avoid 'null' responses in the jsp, run every returned value through a method which returns the empty string for null, or the given string if not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already calling `ResultSet#getString`, which will return a `String`. There's no need to call `toString` in a `String`, so remove that method call for your parameters.

```
listRehber.add(
    new Rehber(
        rs.getString("KISI_ID"),
        rs.getString("AD"),
        rs.getString("SOYAD"),
        rs.getString("UNVANI"),
        rs.getString("GOREVI"),
        rs.getString("FIRMA"),
        rs.getString("ADRES"),
        rs.getString("TEL"),
        rs.getString("FAX"),
        rs.getString("GSM"),
        rs.getString("MAIL"),
        rs.getString("WEB")
    ));
```

Comment: hmm ok :)  you right @Luiggi thank you so much and ı understand what is my problem :)